# Joomla 2.5 show articles under subcategory listing

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a main category ( infertility ) with subcategories (normal life , causes , diagnosis , treatment) , and under each subcategory there is a list of articles . 
I tried all  menu modes , list all cateogories , category list , category blog and all , inorder to display the list of articles under each subcategory in the same page but with no success.
Please advise

I want :
Main category 
-Subcategory 1
--Articles1
--Articles2
-Subcategory 2
--Articles1
--Articles2

What i get is

Main category 
-Subcategory 1
Number of articles 3 
-Subcategory 2
Number of articles 5

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this recently with no joy.  I did, however manage to pull it off in about 5 minutes after installing K2.  Use the 'Latest Items' menutype and instead of selecting the parent category, selecting the all child categories.

Pretty severe solution, but it works.